# How can I sum values from df1 that match another value from df2

Tags: python, list, pandas, sum

How can I sum values from df1 that belong to another value in df2?

I have a really large df, but lets say I have a df like this:

```
df1:

     A     B        C
0   John  Pen       Apple
1   John  Printer   Pie
2   John  Charger   Burger
3   Erick Battery   Pizza
4   Mandy Keyboard  Bread
5   Mandy Phone     Coffee
6   David Computer  Coke
```

And another df:

```
df2:

     A        B  
0   Pen       2
1   Printer   5
2   Charger   11
3   USB       5
4   Keyboard  8
5   Phone     21
6   Cup       3
```

And a third df:

```
df3: 

    A      B
0  Erick  Yes
1  John   Yes
2  David  No 
3  Mandy  Yes
4  Jared  No
5  Lisa   No
```

I want to sum the matching values in a new column in df3

My desired df:

```
    A      B   Sum
0  Erick  Yes  
1  John   Yes  18
2  David  No   
3  Mandy  Yes  29
4  Jared  No
5  Lisa   No
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='B', right_on='A', suffixes=('','1'))
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B1'].sum()
df = pd.merge(df3, df, on='A', how='left').rename(columns={'B1':'Sum'})
#if need remove NaN
df.Sum.fillna('', inplace=True)
print (df)
       A    B Sum
0  Erick  Yes    
1   John  Yes  18
2  David   No    
3  Mandy  Yes  29
4  Jared   No    
5   Lisa   No
```

Comment: I'm sorry jezrael, I realized that I didn't write suffixes... my bad.
This solves it. I'm still new to python and pandas, but learning more everyday, thanks.